# Dynamically set oncomplete event

Tags: javascript, ajax4jsf

In my JSF page, within `<script>` tags I have following content.

> `<script>`
>  
>       `function func() {`
>               `alert("Button clicked");`
>         `}`
>         `window.onload = function() {`
>             `#{rich:element("btn")}.onclick = func;`
>       `}`
>   `</script>`

And I have an a4j button in page body.

> `<a4j:commandButton id="btn" value="save" />`

After the page is loaded I click the button and it successfully displays the alert.
But what I want now is to set the function `func` for the **oncomplete** event of the button. I tried in following way but didn't work. Please help.

> `window.onload = function() {`
>             `#{rich:element("btn")}.oncomplete = func;`
>   `}`

I prefer the answer without jQuery.

Comment: `oncomplete` is an event for the JSF control, not DOM element

Comment: Do buttons have a (client-side) `oncomplete` event? (I don't think so.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes `<a4j:commandButton>` has `oncomplete` event. when I use as `<a4j:commandButton id="btn" value="save" oncomplete="func()"/>` it works.

Comment: @ianpgall : Thanks. I understood why this doesn't work. Is there a way to accomplish this however.

Comment: No, there is no `oncomplete` event in Javascript (as far as this context). When using an `a4j:button`, it runs an AJAX call, and then runs your code that you specify for `oncomplete`. Anything you specify for `onclick` is run before the AJAX call. As far as I know, there is no way to tap into what should be run after the AJAX call, because the code is put directly in the `<input>` tag that is rendered.

Comment: @ianpgall : Thanks, you gave me some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround. 
I added the function to the `oncomplete` event initially, and change the body of the function at runtime.

> `<a4j:commandButton id="btn" value="save" oncomplete="func()"/>`

Then within my `<script></script>` I added the following code.

> `<script>`
>          `var func;`
>          `window.onload = function() {`
>                   `func = function(){`
>                          `alert("Button clicked");`
>                 `}`
>          `}`
>   `</script>`